# print name using for loop php

Tags: php, html

Using for loop in PHP can we have numbers associate with a variable name?

ex:

```
$name1="hi";
$name2="khj";

for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++)
{
echo ..
}
```

How can we print $name1 and $name2 using for loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is called [variable interpolation](http://hydrogen.informatik.tu-cottbus.de/wiki/index.php/PHP_Variable_Interpolation).

```
$name1="hi";
$name2="khj";

for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++) {
    $var = 'name' . $i;
    echo $$var;
}
```

**Note:** There are multiple syntaxes for variable interpolation in PHP. Also, I modified your loop to start at `1`.

Answer (score 5):

```
    for($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++)
    {   
        echo $name{$i};
    }
```

It would be way easier to put it in an array though, that's what we have them for.

```
    $names = array();
    $names[1] = 'A';
    $names[2] = 'B';

    foreach($names as $name)
    {
        echo $name; 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

put this in the for loop:

```
echo ${'name'.$i}."\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Better to use something like:-

```
$names[] = $name1;
$names[] = $name2;

foreach($names as $name){
    echo $name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This print the name1 and name2 .And i value must be start from 1

```
      for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++)
       {
         echo ${'name'.$i}."<br>";
        }
```

Comment: This is not what the user is asking.

Comment: Don't think so. Test it yourself. Your output, as you noted, is `name1` and `name2`.

Comment: If your answer "matches" with everybody else, why bother writing a new answer. Just upvote the one you think is the best answer.

Comment: sorry every body done wrong in over look.Now i edited my answer